# Best practice for uploading app to Appstore for Client

Tags: ios, app-store

im a developer and i have my own developer-account for IOS. I have a Prototype-App which i want to sell to my clients. All of my clients do not have a MAC and a own developer account. Im searching for the easiest way for me and for my clients for uploading the app on their dev-accounts.

So i thought, that i let my customer open a own developer-account (99$/year) and send me only the login-data. Then i can prepare and upload the app on their account. Is this possible? Can i upload from my MAC (XCode) to a different Dev-Account?

Comment: Yes it is possible to "upload from my MAC (XCode) to a different Dev-Account". I am currently uploading to three different accounts and it works well. You just need to choose that particular account at the time of upload when prompted.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to accomplish what you want is for the client to setup their own dev account but instead of giving you their credentials, they should add you as a collaborator. Given that you will be handling everything for them, they may as well make you an admin (although a technical role may work as well).

One of the annoying thing with iTunesConnect is that a login can only be attached to one account.

> If you already have an iTunes Connect account for distributing another
>   media type besides apps (music, TV, movies, or books) or for
>   participating in the Volume Purchase Program, the same Apple ID cannot
>   be used to manage apps. When you enroll in the iOS Developer Program
>   or Mac Developer Program, you'll need to use a different Apple ID. ([source](https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/itunes-connect/))

<del>So you will need to create a new login for yourself. I do this with clients by creating custom email address for each one. Say my client is Odyssey, I would create an Apple account "odyseey@mydomain.com" and have them add that account into their iTunesConnect.</del>

Thanks to Vijayts in the comments: You can actually append `+something` to your email address to reuse the same one with a different login id (so same email, different login basically). So if my normal ID is ***firo@mydomain.com*** I can use ***firo+odyseey@mydomain.com***.

This gives the client the most control, while allowing you to accomplish everything you need.

Comment: Would be interesting here to note that we can acheive this by <your present apple id username>+<any random name>@<your present apple id domain>.com . This will send the iTunes Connect details to the same Apple ID. Been working for sometime now. Not sure when/whether it will be closed.

Comment: Really? I didn't know that, that would be great! I'll have to try that out, surprised I haven't heard of that before. I am assuming the `+` is literal ("firo+odyseey@mydomain.com" if my original id is "firo@mydomain.com")?